# NextJs dynamic open graph meta tags not rendering for facebook debugger

Tags: reactjs, next.js, meta-tags, share-open-graph

I have tried to include meta tags using base "Head" feature of NextJs, react-helmet and next-seo packages.They all works fine on client side and show meta tags in inspect tool. But When I try to detect it using facebook debugger tool or any other open graph tags detector, it does not work.

May be something to do with server side rendering of meta tags but I have not found enough material to implement server side meta tags in NextJs framework.

Comment: Been having the same problem. Driving me crazy. What I can tell you is that the same code, `next export`ed and statically served with https://surge.sh works. So it seems there's something wrong with Vercel. One thing I realized is that Vercel uses Brotli compression instead of Gzip (as requested by Facebook guidelines).

Comment: Just found a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62404156/12968082 here

Comment: Take a look at this blog post as well: https://kulkarniankita.com/next.js/nextjs-head-with-seo-deep-dive

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Redux Persist?

Since there is a known issue with Redux Persist which disables SSR. 
Disabling PersistGate server-side seems to fix the issue. [Github Issue Link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8240)

```
return process.browser ? (
        <PersistGate persistor={store.__persistor} loading={<div>Loading</div>}>
            <ToastProvider>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </ToastProvider>
        </PersistGate>
    ) : (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ToastProvider>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </ToastProvider>
            </Provider>
        );
```

Comment: What about project without Redux, just Next.js? with SSR it only delivers initial (default) OG data, this results similar symptoms as everything looks correct in inspects but right-click view page source does not have the page specified og data.