# next-seo not render to <head> in SSR?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

The SEO tags don't get rendered in SSR when using the `next-seo` package.
I have tried

```
<NextSeo />
```

and

```
<Head><NextSeo /></Head>
```

to render code in a `next.js` page, but no luck.

Can anyone have any workaround solutions by using `next-seo` with SSR?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found that the reason is `<PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}></PersistGate>`.
Because I am using redux and persist-redux in react.

If I take out the `<PersistGate>` line, the meta tags are fine.

_app.js:

```
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                <StylesProvider>
                    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                        <CssBaseline />
                        <Component {...pageProps} />
                    </ThemeProvider>
                </StylesProvider>
            </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
    );
```

What is the problem there? I must use redux+persist-redux....

Comment: Just found a workaround: [stackoverflow.com/a/62404156/12968082](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62404156/12968082) here

Answer (score 0):

In my case works only like this:

```
<>
   <NextSeo
            title={titleSEO}
            description={descriptionSEO}
            openGraph={openGraph}
   />
   <Head>
            <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
   </Head>
   ...
</>
```

- next: 12.1.4 in SSR mode
- next-seo: 5.5.0